# List gets filled with only one row from JSON, should get filled with many rows

Tags: java, json

Hello I have a JSF application that makes a GET Request to an API gets a JSON and from that JSON gets an elements and fills a JSF Datatable with it. I would like to fill the datatable with all elements but only one gets added.

This is my Java code :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "logic", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Logic  {

    static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    static JSONObject jo = null;
    static JSONArray cat = null;

    private ArrayList<Logic> logics;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String cif2;

    public void connect()  {

        try {   
            URL url = new URL("xxx");
            URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                sb.append(inputLine+"\n");
                in.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }

    private String cif;

    public ArrayList<Logic> getLogics() {
        return logics;
    }

    public Logic() throws ParseException {
        connect();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
        cat = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
        for(int i = 0; i < cat.size(); i++) {
            jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(i);
            cif2 = jo.get("cif").toString();
            logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2)));
        }
    }

    public Logic(String cif) throws ParseException {
        this.cif = cif;
    }

    public String getCif() {
        return cif;
    }

    public void setCif(String cif) {
        this.cif = cif;
    }
}
```

The code that I wrote to make the insertion is this:

```
public Logic() throws ParseException {
    connect();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
    cat = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
    for(int i = 0; i < cat.size(); i++) {
    jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(i);
    cif2 = jo.get("cif").toString();
    logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2)));
    }

}
```

It does a for loop over the json but it only adds the last value.

I would like to add all values

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSF datatables never get populated from json, they get populated from a java list. So if your loop fails to add all, that is a pure java/json thing, not JSF related. And calling the api is also not JSF related. All pure in your (plain) java code.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but could you tell me what is wrong with my code ? I took data from JSON and I put in a variable that I try to load in a java list but it only loads one value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise the `logics` with empty arraylist.

```
private ArrayList<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<>();
```

And

Replace `logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2)));` with `logics.add(new Logic(cif2));`

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the culprit

```
logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2)));
```

As you can see, it will create new instance of the logics everytime the loop iterates instead of adding/append the parsed value to the list. you should create a variable to accept data, then append/add it something like:

```
logics.append(  new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2))) );
```

Are you using jackson-core-2.9.6? You might want to use `ObjectMapper` rather than using `JSONParser`.

You might want to convert this lines of code

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
cat = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
for(int i = 0; i < cat.size(); i++) {
    jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(i);
    cif2 = jo.get("cif").toString();
    logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(cif2)));
}
```

to

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//Create the ObjectMapper

// readValue accepts 2 param. string to be converted, and Object class/type to be used on mapping the data.
logics = objectMapper.readValue(sb.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Logic>>(){});
//If you have a adapter class to handle the entire JSON Record, you can use it to replace Logic.
```

It is much simpler to read and use.

PS: I notice that you are retrieving data from a larger set of JSON. If that is the case, you should have an adapter/bridge/help (whatever you want to call that) class to accept/map that JSON rather than using the same class. Inside that adapter class, you can add a method to extract data, list, and other things you want to get from the JSON record.

```
//Make sure you have correct attribute as to the JSON you are going to map in this object
class JSONReceived{
    private . . . // attributes of the JSON


    //getters and setters

    public List<Mesaje> getMesajeList(){
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Then you can use these lines instead of earlier lines of codes.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//Create the ObjectMapper

JSONReceived json = objectMapper.readValue(sb.toString(), JSONReceived.class); 
logics = json. getMesajeList();
```

That way, it will help you find bug in record size and other related problems.